# Dictionary Looping

Tags: python, string, dictionary

As you will understand from my question, I am new to programming and as most people who are new to this,
I am having issues comprehending some of the code. I came across the following code in Python which
translates some words from German to English and returns a string of the translation:

```
deu2eng = {
'ich':'I',
'gehe':'go',
'nach':'to',
'die':'the',
'kirche':'church'}

def trans(eng2deu):
    translation = ''
    for word in eng2deu.split():
        if word in deu2eng:
            translation+= deu2eng[word] + ' '
        else:
            translation += word + ' '
    return translation
```

When I run the following it works:
`trans('ich gehe nach die kirche')`

However there are some issues. I can't get to understand how I can get it to be case insensitive (e.g. if I type Kirche instead of kirche, it will return Kirche instead of church). I tried using the lower()
method to no avail. But most importantly, I do not understand the following line and why it works:

```
translation+= deu2eng[word] + ' '
```

From what you can infer, this is quite basic, but I would like to fully comprehend what is happening with this code as I am stuck in the 2 aforementioned things.

Comment: `translation+= deu2eng[word] + ' '` Juste before that line you are testing the condition to know if the iterated word has a translation available. If yes, then you run the mentioned line. In this line, you add (concatenation with `+=`) the translation of your word and a space. To get the translation, you use dict[key]. Since, the translation key is the not translated word you have deu2eng[word] (with deu2eng your dict).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It always helps to put in comments to read through new code specially if you're new to programming.

```
# Initializes your basic "translation" for each word, i.e. ich = I
# Notice that ich is in all lower case letters, which affects your matching in your trans function
deu2eng = {
'ich':'I',
'gehe':'go',
'nach':'to',
'die':'the',
'kirche':'church'}

def trans(eng2deu):
    translation = ''
    # Start of your for loop, this does 2 things:
    # (1) Splits up your sentence using the space character, i.e. ich gehe nach die kirche => [ich gehe, nach, die, kirche]
    # (2) Loops through your split up sentence word per word
    for word in eng2deu.split():
        # Now we check if the word is in deu2eng,
        # i.e. is ich a key in deu2eng (a key is case sensitive)
        if word in deu2eng:
            # If we find the key, then we get the corresponding value of our word, i.e. ich = I, and then append it to our translation variable.
            translation += deu2eng[word] + ' '
        else:
            # If not, then we use the original word
            translation += word + ' '
    return translation
```

Now notice your if statement `if word in deu2eng` which we mention checks if a specific `key` to a value in `deu2eng`, we also mention that the check itself is case sensitive which if it fails defaults to your `else` case. So to *fix* your issues with it not matching correctly, we simply change the `word` to its lower case value using `lower()`:

```
key = word.lower()
if key in deu2eng:
    translation+= deu2eng[key] + ' '
else:
    translation += word + ' '
```

Although you could simplify that by just using:

```
translations += deu2eng.get(word.lower(), word) + ' '
```

Always good to have a read through the python documentation as well, here are some references to what you're looking for:

[dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

[split](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 4):

To make it case-insensitive, change the `for` line to:

```
for word in lower(eng2deu).split()
```

Here's the step-by-step explanation of `translation+= deu2eng[word] + ' '`:

1. Get the translation of `word` from the `deu2eng` dictionary.
2. Concatenate a space to the end of that.
3. Set `translation` to the concatenation of `translation` and that string.

Remember that `x += y` is just short for `x = x + y`. So

```
translation+= deu2eng[word] + ' '
```

means

```
translation = translation + deu2eng[word] + ' '
```

Comment: Thanks, however what I don't get is this part: deu2eng[word]. It uses word as an index and then returns index 1, or the value more precisely of the dictionary

Comment: That's how you get a value from a dictionary. `word` contains the key, `deu2eng[word]` is the value that corresponds to the key. This is basic Python, you should learn that from a tutorial.

Comment: Might also be useful to point out that for strings (and lists) `+` is the concatenation/append operator and not an actual sum

Comment: @Barmar the question is literally "I don't understand the basics of the language" and you took the time to explain that `a += b` is `a = a + b`. Unlike the meaning of `+=`, the overloading of the `+` operator is not as trivial as it may look to an experienced user.

Comment: Also, that's actually part of the question: *I do not understand the following line and why it works ...*

Comment: @GPhilo I didn't realize it was that basic until he asked for an explanation of `deu2eng[word]` in a comment. Otherwise I probably wouldn't have answered.

Comment: @GPhilo That line combines multiple things, I thought that made it complex enough to warrant explaining. You'll notice that I assumed he understood `deu2eng[word]`.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got an explanation, but I would recommend changing the code in a way that might make it clearer. (and technically, more efficient if your strings become very long):

```
deutsch_to_english = {
    'ich':'I',
    'gehe':'go',
    'nach':'to',
    'die':'the',
    'kirche':'church',
}

def translate(sentence_to_translate, translator = deutsch_to_english):
    translated_words = []
    for word in sentence_to_translate.split():
        word = word.lower()
        try:
            translated_word = translator[word]
            translated_words.append(translated_word)
        except KeyError:
            translated_words.append(word)
        translated_sentence = " ".join(translated_words)
    return translated_sentence
```

I've tried to use variable names in such a way that the code becomes clearer. I really recommend using longer, clearer variable names. I've also used lists and try/catch to be a little more pythonic, I think it would be worth your while tyring to understand this code snippet in addition to the one you posted as this one is a bit more standard 'pythonic' way to write this.

Comment: This is also something I would recommend as well, having descriptive variable names also help a lot when reading through code as it doesn't leave you guessing what the variable is for.

Answer (score 1):

Working code with minimum changes:

```
deu2eng = {
    'ich':'I',
    'gehe':'go',
    'nach':'to',
    'die':'the',
    'kirche':'church',
}


def trans(eng2deu):
    translation = ''
    for word in eng2deu.split():
        word = word.lower()    # ADDED
        if word in deu2eng:
            translation+= deu2eng[word] + ' '
        else:
            translation += word + ' '
    return translation


assert trans('ich gehe nach die Kirche') == 'I go to the church '
```

Try to understand this code:

```
deu2eng = {
    'ich':'I',
    'gehe':'go',
    'nach':'to',
    'die':'the',
    'kirche':'church',
}

assert deu2eng['ich'] == 'I'    # Gives the value of `ich`
assert deu2eng['gehe'] == 'go'  # Gives the value of `gehe`

print(deu2eng['not_present'])   # Raises: KeyError: 'not_present', because the key 'not_present' is not there in the ditionary.
```